# Kotlin: Constructor of inner class can be called only with receiver of containing class

Tags: constructor, kotlin, inner-classes

I was trying inner classes in Kotlin and came across this error but didn't quite understand it. I tried to look at the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html) but didn't quite get any direction as to how outer classes can access inner class constructors

```
class OuterClass {

  fun someFun(): InnerClassSuper {
    return InnerClassX("Hello") //Error: Constructor of inner class InnerClassX can be called only with receiver of containing class
  }

  sealed class InnerClassSuper {

    inner class InnerClassX(val x: String): InnerClassSuper()

  }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone explains the error and directs how to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code basically means that `InnerClassX` is an inner class of `InnerClassSuper`, not `OuterClass`, so the error means you need to provide a receiver object of `InnerClasssSuper` upon construction of `InnerClassX`.

At this point, Kotlin allows having neither an `inner sealed` class nor a derived class for a `sealed` class as an `inner` class of another class.

You can, however, make an `abstract` class derived from the `sealed` one and inherit from it inside the `OuterClass`:

```
sealed class SealedClassSuper {
    abstract class SealedClassChild(val x: String): SealedClassSuper()
}

class OuterClass {
    inner class InnerClassX(x: String) : SealedClassSuper.SealedClassChild(x)

    fun someFun(): SealedClassSuper {
        return InnerClassX("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

We can use it this way too

OuterClassName().NestedClassName()

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to place the definition of your `InnerClassX` outside of the sealed `InnerClassSuper`, then the `InnerClassX` will become an inner class of `OuterClass` and will be able to be instantiated and to reference its members:

```
class OuterClass {

  fun someFun(): InnerClassSuper {
    return InnerClassX("Hello") // this is legit now
  }

  sealed class InnerClassSuper

  inner class InnerClassX(val x: String): InnerClassSuper()

}
```